# Laravel Mysql Select from two tables and join result on a third table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I wonder if its possible to select two tables and join a third table

I have 3 tables:

**upvotes**
-id (PK)
-voteOn (FK) - points to users PK
-voteBy (FK) - points to users PK
-vote (Int)
-voteAdded (Int) - unix timestamp

**downvotes**
-id (PK)
-voteOn (FK) - points to users PK
-voteBy (FK) - points to users PK
-vote (tinyInteger)
-voteAdded (Int) - unix timestamp

**users**
id (PK)
username

What I now want to do is ~ select ALL votes from the tables  **upvotes** and **downvotes** where voteOn = 2 then join table **users** on voteBy orderBy voteAdded Asc

More or less I want to get all votes on a specific user then join the users table so that I can get the username of the person who placed the vote

Comment: Am I missing the reason for having separate tables for upvotes and downvotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use the DB facade to achieve this which will generate an sql query that is fired on the db

```
  $users = DB::table("users AS a") 
                   ->select(array("a.id as user_id", "a.username", "b.voteOn as upvote_on",
                "b.vote as upvote", "b.voteAdded as upvote_added","c.voteOn as downvote_on",  "c.vote as downvote",
                  "c.voteAdded as downvote_added"))
                   ->join("upvotes AS b",  "a.id", "=", "b.voteBy")
                   ->join("downvotes AS c",  "a.id", "=", "c.voteBy")
                   ->orderBy("b.voteAdded", "asc") 
                   ->get();
```

Then you can loop through the users using foreach

```
   foreach($users as $user) {
      $user->user_id;
      //use the alias as used in the select chained function 
    }
```

That should work